# Magento2 - Cannot Resize Images due to error message In CLI

Tags: magento2, error, product-images, cli, image-resizing

I'm currently trying to run the image resize command in the CLI for Magento2.3.2 but it keeps coming up with the following error as soon as I run the command:

```
mysite@dx1287:~/httpdocs$ php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

I get the error:

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: Read Error: truncated data  in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 72
```

Does anyone now why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This error might occurred due to an unsupported file format or bad quality of PNG image. imagepng should have a valid quality format between 1 and 9.

Check the var/log directory for the corrupted catalog image, then remove the corrupted image & re-add the updated image. Hopefully it will fix your issue!

Comment: Thank you. Which log file is this likely to be found in?

Comment: Check exception.log or debug.log file for reference hints.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check these.

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid that neither of these logs contain an error relating to an image file.